# "Only entities in this entityManager may be saved" when deleting a breeze entity while subscribed to entityChanged event handler

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, typescript, breeze

I have a mapping table for a many-to-many relationship. I've subscribed to the entityChanged event and in the handler I call saveChanged. When I click on a kogrid row, an click eventhandler is called that removes the current record from the krid and from the database.

The problem is that I get a **"Only entities in this entityManager may be saved"** message in the fail of the saveChanged, though the record is actually removed from the database. The interface of the entity is defined as follows:

```
export interface TenantMemberLinkBreeze extends breeze.Entity
{
    TenantMemberId: KnockoutObservable<System.IGuid>; 
    MemberId: KnockoutObservable<System.IGuid>;
    TenantId: KnockoutObservable<System.IGuid>;
    InviterId: KnockoutObservable<System.IGuid>;
    Status: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    CreatedOn: KnockoutObservable<Date>; 
    Inviter: KnockoutObservable<User>;
    Member: KnockoutObservable<User>;
    Tenant: KnockoutObservable<Tenant>;
}
```

Digging into the breeze source code, I see that in the function getEntitiesToSave there is a comparison if the entities' entitymanager is the same as the function parameter em. And here is where the exception occurs. It looks like the entity has detached from the context (e.entityAspect.entityManager is null). JavaScript code:

```
function getEntitiesToSave(em, entities) {
    var entitiesToSave;
    if (entities) {
        entitiesToSave = entities.filter(function (e) {
            if (e.entityAspect.entityManager !== em) {
                throw new Error("Only entities in this entityManager may be saved");
            }
            return !e.entityAspect.entityState.isDetached();
        });
    } else {
        entitiesToSave = em.getChanges();
    }
    return entitiesToSave;
}
```

The eventhandler for entityChanged is fired 6 times:

- AttachOnQuery (entityState is unchanged)
- PropertyChanged (navigational property 1 is set to null, entityState becomes Deleted
- PropertyChanged (navigational property 2 is set to null, entityState Deleted
- PropertyChanged (navigational property 3 is set to null, entityState Deleted
- EntityStateChange
- Detach (envityState becomes Detached)

The entityChanged eventhandler (TypeScript):

```
this.SubscriptionKey = this.BreezeEntityManager.entityChanged.subscribe((data: breeze.EntityChangedEventArgs) => {
    if (data.entityAction === breeze.EntityAction.PropertyChange) {
        return setTimeout(() => {
            this.BreezeEntityManager.saveChanges(<breeze.Entity[]> new Array(data.entity))
                        .fail((error) => toastr.error("Failed. (more info: " + error + ")"));
                }, 0);
            }
        });
```

The code (event handler) that triggers the delete (TypeScript):

```
return this.BreezeEntityManager.fetchEntityByKey("TenantMemberLink", tenantMemberLinkId)
.then((data: breeze.EntityByKeyResult) =>
    {
       data.entity.entityAspect.setDeleted();
    }
```

So It looks to me that the entity is detached before all changes are committed, but I don't know where to search anymore. Do you have any ideas?

EDIT:
The issue goes away when changing:

```
 this.BreezeEntityManager.saveChanges(<breeze.Entity[]> new Array(data.entity))
```

into:

```
this.BreezeEntityManager.saveChanges()
```

That is a work around, but I'm trying to understand this (for me unexpected) behavior.

Comment: What is the entity you are passing in to the new Array of entities?

Comment: I've added the entity interface of the entity concerned to the problem description

Answer (score 0):

This may be a timing issue with your setTimeout call. Is it possible that you are trying 'delete' the same entity more than once?  If so the first delete would have detached the entity which would cause the 2nd delete to fail with this error.

The fact that the problem goes away when you call saveChanges without any parameters supports this hypothesis because that call only tries to save entities that have not already been saved.

To debug this I would wrap your failing *saveChanges* call with a another function that checks the state of each entity before you call breeze's *saveChanges* method and see which entity/*entityAspect* has a null *entityManager* property.